# How does the human body power itself?

Tags: energy

This query can be divided into sub-queries:

1. What form/s of energy does the human body "run" on?
2. Why/for what are these particular forms of energy required?
3. From what can these types of energy be derived?
4. How efficiently (less waste) does the body use energy?

Looking for a simple, effective answer with little to no jargon (distinction between pertinent use of terminology and showboating).

Comment: This question is very broad, and you can easily google part of it and show your research. If you narrow this down and add your research, I'd be happy to withdraw my close vote  and my downvote, and even to answer it.

Comment: If you had read the info about this site you would have seen that is for students of biology. Biology is a specialised subject with its own language. This is not jargon but a vocabulary to describe specific entities and concepts not encountered by the layman. To suggest its use is "showboating" is insulting to members of this list. If you have such a detailed list of informational requirements you need to learn some metabolism from a standard text, or find a website that provides a naive account of such processes, replete with half truths and false analogies.

Answer (score 1):

The question is broad and can hardly be fully answered in a single post. I will be very brief hoping it will help you and push you to seek for more knowledge.

Humans, like all other animals (or almost all) are chemo-organotroph. This mean we get our energy from the food we eat and we release this energy through oxydation. It is therefore chemical energy that we're using. We are then storing this energy into another chemical called [ATP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_triphosphate). Note that not only humans use ATP but any living thing on earth uses ATP (or GTP I think). ATP is then used (ATP loses one phosphate group and becomes ADP) to perform specific action (such as the use of a trans-membrane pump or the contraction of a muscle fiber).

You should have a look at [wikipedia > Primary nutritional groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_nutritional_groups) as well as  [wikipedia > chemotrophs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemotroph) and eventually [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/22043/are-there-any-multicellular-forms-of-life-which-exist-without-consuming-other-fo).

For more information, please consider having a look at wikipedia and if you can't find feel free to ask your question in a new post. Always attempt to narrow your post down to a single, clearly defined question.