# Is a nature possible where animals do not kill each other?

Tags: zoology

like the title suggests, i always wondered if its possible that nature would work without animals killing each other. Where they just eat plants. Like one special plant for each animal. If they eat to much of them away they also will stop multiplying to much, so there will never be too much of one species etc, terefore balance. I am sure there could be other controlling mechanism for balances.

:)

Comment: I suppose your question could be rephrased, "how could predators never evolve?" This type of question should be asked on [worldbuilding.SE](worldbuilding.stackexchange.com), not on a science website. Note that plenty of points are unclear in your question. How about cells phagocyting? Is this allowed in your imaginary world? How about competition leading to death of other individuals?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Are there any multicellular forms of life which exist without consuming other forms of life in some manner?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/22043/are-there-any-multicellular-forms-of-life-which-exist-without-consuming-other-fo)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unclear and in essence is not open to empirical testing and is therefore unsuitable on a scientific website.

Comment: No. Because a spiderwebs can't catch herbs.

Comment: I'm not sure how a spider would catch herbs in its web.

Answer (score 1):

No, even herbivores will eat other animals, and predation goes down ot the cellular level.  Also something has to be ating your dead and will have a huge evolutionary pressure to evolve toward predation with no predators present.

Animals by definition have a much better profile of nutrients for other animals.

Deer routinely kill and eat birds, eggs and even dead rabbits. In nature food is food and evolution does not care where you get it from. Carnivores will and have evolved from an herbivorous ancestor when no carnivores are present.